# Second For Loop Value Depend On First For Loop Value

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have two for loops in the following code. I wish to have the following value when the for loops are executed.

- When n = 1, o = 0,1
- When n = 2, o = 2,3
- When n = 3, o = 4,5
- When n = 4, o = 6,7
- When n = 5, o = 8,9

It is possible? If it is possible, please show me the way on how to do it. Thanks.

```
for (int n = 1; n < dates.Count - 1; n++)
{
    for (int o = n; o < n + 2; o++)
    {
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b><ins>Place Number </ins></b>" + "<b><ins>" + o + "</b></ins>" + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Place Name: </b>" + touristAttractionName[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Address: </b>" + touristAttractionFormattedAddress[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Phone Number: </b>" + touristAttractionFormattedPhoneNumber[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>International Phone Number: </b>" + touristAttractionInternationalPhoneNumber[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Website: </b>" + touristAttractionWebsite[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b><ins>Opening Hours</ins></b>" + "<br/>";
        for (int p = 0; p < 7; p++)
        {
            TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += touristAttractionOpeningHours[o, p] + "<br/>";
        }
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b><ins>Rating & Review</ins></b>" + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Overall Rating: </b>" + touristAttractionRating[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Author: </b>" + touristAttractionReviewAuthor[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Rating: </b>" + touristAttractionReviewRating[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<b>Review: </b>" + touristAttractionReviewText[o] + "<br/>";
        TravelPlanTouristAttractionNWeatherLabel.Text += "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Was entirely necessary to necessary paste all the other code, you could have probably just given an example with 3-4 lines

Comment: Hi. @TheGeneral Actually I just having problem with the for loop of o as I can't make the value of o depends of the value of n.

Comment: please post the [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TanYihWei for n = 5, will it be 7,8 ?

Comment: If you started n at zero it would be easier and then make time[n - 1].  This should work : for (int o = 2 * (n - 1); o <= (2 * (n - 1)) + 1; o++)

Comment: Hi. @Amit It will be 8,9.

Comment: Hi. @jdweng Will try on this formula. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. @jdweng Your formula is working. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, `o` is in range `2*n-2 to 2*n-1`, so you would go with something like:

```
for (int n = 1; n < dates.Count - 1; n++){
   for (int o = 2*n-2; o < 2*n; o++) {
      //Do your magic here
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi. @Caldazar. Will try on your formula. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. @Caldazar. Your formula is working. Marked it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
for (int n = 0; n < dates.Count -1, n++)
{
    for (int o = (n-1)*2; o < 2n; o++)
    {
        //Add your logic here :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. @CRoberts Will try on your formula. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. @CRoberts Your formula is working for me but Caldazar is the first one to answer so I will mark his formula as accepted answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @TanYihWei No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

as i could see a pattern in your requirement. and by that pattern, o will be always sequentially incremented. while n will be incremented from 1 to date's count.

So basically you can derive o without calculating any formula on n.

***(make sure if you want to start your loop from n = some other number and then you expect o should hold initial value as per n, it will not. But i don't see that to be a case as per your question)***

do it like this,

```
int o = 0;
for (int n = 1; n < dates.Count - 1; n++)
{
  ....
     for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
     {
          // this loop should be running for two iterations only.
          //even if loop is on k, use o
          o++;
     }
}
```

but if you want a relation. o's loop is ending just before 2xn's value and o's loop should be run 2 times.

So relative loop can start from

o = (2*n) - 2 to o < 2*n.

```
for(int o = (2*n) - 2 ; o < 2*n; o++)
```

Comment: Hi. @Amit Will try on your formula. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. @Amit Your code is working but Caldazar is the first one to answer so I will mark his formula as accepted answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @TanYihWei that is totally your call. I have just shown you a way where you don't have to be dependant on 'n' for deciding values for 'o' .

Answer (score -1):

You want:

When n = 1, o = 0,1

When n = 2, o = 2,3

When n = 3, o = 4,5

When n = 4, o = 6,7

so try:

```
for (int n = 1; n < dates.Count - 1; n++)
{
    int o_start = 0; // covers n = 1
    if(n == 2)
      o_start = 2;
    if(n == 3)
      o_start = 4;
    if(n == 4)
      o_start = 6;

    for (int o = o_start; o < o_start + 2; o++)
    {
        // execute o-loop
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you may define an array containing the indices, access them via [n].

Comment: what about n = 10, 15, and 20 ? (still i don't have downvoted so i dont have reason for that)

Comment: Without edit, the question only containted n 0 [1..4]. OP was not asking for a general rule. Your answer is however more generic :)